# JQuery table headers manipulation

Tags: jquery, html

I have the a html structure with table header on which I am trying to set the width with JQuery with the aim of wrapping the text it works for all but one of the headers- 'Name of Company lawyer with responsibility'.

My code is in the JSFiddle link below

http://jsfiddle.net/nQKfe/1/

Thanks,

Comment: That better be auto generated HTML! Otherwise ew.

Comment: yes its sharepoint's auto gen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I see correctly, the table with "Name of Company lawyer with responsibility" is inside a TH tag. And that TH tag has CSS class "ms-vh". So if you apply the width for this TH, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`<TD class="ms-vh" noWrap fixed_bound>`

Your TD with the name "Name of Company lawyer with responsibility" has class `vh` instead of `vb` Which I presume is a typo

Here it ["works"](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/nQKfe/4/)

To update and place **emphasis** on the fact that your html is a **mess** can you show me what auto generates your html?

There should be a significantly better way to create the HTML your creating.

```
<table>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th> 
  <th> // here is your content for that value
    <!-- start deletion of unneccesary html junk here -->
    <div> // opening a div? :S ok fair enough
      <table> // what are you doing?
        <tr><td>
          <table> // Seriously? another table?
            <tr><td>
             <!-- end deletion of html junk here -->
              // your content
              ...
```

This is a classic case of `<table>` abuse. The div and the double nested table is ridiculous. Find a better html generation tool.

Comment: hmmm its not wrapping that column

Comment: @nav your issue is that your html is not uniformly structured and frankly a complete mess. Stop abusing `<table>`'s

Comment: Raynos you did see my comment about this being autogenerated from SharePoint right? :)